# Python to_datetime (from int/float in 3 columns)

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have 3 columns: year (int), month (int), day (float) in my dataset.
I want to create one date column using to_datetime.

Link to the picture of sample data: https://ibb.co/kSyz4Y0

**Link to the whole dataset:** https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jakevdp/data-CDCbirths/master/births.csv

I tried to convert these 3 columns into 3 int or 3 strings but I always get the same error - day is out of range.

My questions are:

1) What column format should I have in order to be able to use to_datimetime - int or string?

2) Can I or how can I create a date from 3 columns with to_datetime? Or do I have to concat these 3 columns first?

3) How can I eliminate this "day out of range problem"?
I asked dr Google but none of the solutions worked for me.

```
data['td'] = pd.to_datetime(data['year'])

data['tm2'] = td + timedelta(days=1)
```

How to add month and day columns to the first line?

Answer (score 1):

1. Both int and str are fine, you just have to change the float type of your Day column. It's unrealistic anyway, we don't fractional days in dates.
2. `date_series = pd.to_datetime(df)` will give you datetime Series, which you can then append to your initial dataframe.

Test Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Year', 'Month', 'Day'])
data = data.append({'Year': 2019, 'Month': 10, 'Day': 20}, ignore_index=True)
date_series = pd.to_datetime(data)
data['Date'] = date_series
```

Output of `data`:

```
    Year    Month   Day Date
0   2019    10      20  2019-10-20
```

**EDIT**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Gender', 'No. of Births'])
data = data.append({'Year': 2019, 'Month': 10, 'Day': 20, 'Gender': 'M', 'No. of Births': 5}, ignore_index=True)

date_prep = data.iloc[:, 0:3]
date_series = pd.to_datetime(date_prep)
data['Date'] = date_series
```

Comment: So the order is: 1) change float to int 2) create datetime series with your code 3) append this series to my dataframe? And it will create dates from my 3 columns, year/month/day? How can I do this?

Comment: Correct. Basically, just substituting your actual data in place of my dummy variables here should do it. Unless, you have other columns in the dataframe, then you can specify which columns to convert to datetime by index. If you could add a sample of what your data looks like, it would probably help me give you a more detailed answer.

Comment: In total I have 5 columns in my dataset (year - int, month - int, day - float, gender - str , number of births - int). I have problem with the third point - how to append dateseries to my existing dataset with 2 other columns?

Comment: @Ela Please see edit above. Basically, you'll separate the three y/m/d columns into a subset, create a datetime series from that and append it (the last line does exactly that).

Comment: First of all, I am very grateful for your help. Secondly, I do not know if I do sth wrong or where is the problem - your code works but it creates only one new row and I do not see data from my original dataset. There is a new date column but without my dataset. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No problem, and I am sorry if I am not understanding you correctly. To do this with your original dataset, you must make sure that the "data" dataframe contains your data, and not the dummy "data" I have created above for test purposes. Are you performing the code with your own variables?

Comment: I try but when I use the last 3 lines of your code with my data I get this error: "cannot assemble the datetimes: day is out of range for month". I have 5 columns and my dataset is not empty :)

Comment: @Ela Can I ask you to post a sample of your data, please?

Comment: I edited my first post and added a link to the screenshot of my sample data.

Comment: @Ela Thank you! Here, I uploaded a gist using your sample. Should work: https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/Aegis-X303/3c3d02e353eba51a6b0b8875e3d08570

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you. But can I make it work for the whole dataset (I inserted a link) without "cannot assemble the datetimes: day is out of range for month" error? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I see the problem now. You have NaN values in 'day' and that makes it impossible to convert column to int() and that makes the whole problem with datetime. You need to drop the NaN values first.

Comment: I dropped the NaN in day column and filtered out day 99. But I still cannot figure out how to pass all the values from year, month, day into datetime without "day is out of range for month" error.

Comment: Can you please show your code step-by-step? I'm not exactly sure where this error is coming from.